# Ignore special characters from the stored data while doing search query in Elastic search

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I have my elastic search data stored in the following format:

```
{
    "person_name": "Abraham Benjamin deVilliers",
    "name": "Abraham",
    "office": {
        "name": "my_office"
    }
},
{
    "person_name": "Johnny O'Ryan",
    "name": "O'Ryan",
    "office": {
        "name": "Johnny O'Ryan"
    }
},
......
```

And i have match query to search based on `person_name`,`name` and `office.name` as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "O'Ryan",
      "type":       "best_fields",
      "fields":     [ "person_name", "name", "office.name" ],
      "operator":"and"
    }
  }
}
```

And its working fine and i am getting expected result for query fields which are exactly matching the `name` or `person_name` or `office.name` as below.

```
{
    "person_name": "Johnny O'Ryan",
    "name": "O'Ryan",
    "office": {
        "name": "Johnny O'Ryan"
    }
}
```

Now i want to enable the search to return the same response when the user passes the query field `ORyan` instead if `O'Ryan`, ignoring the `Single quote (')` from the stored result.

Is there is a way to do it while doing elastic search query or do i need to ignore the special characters while storing the data in elastic search ?.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a tokenizer: [Tokenizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html)

In your case, you can try something like

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "letter", 
  "filter":[],
  "text" : "O'Ryan is good"
}
```

It will produce the following tokens:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "O",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 1,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "Ryan",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "is",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "good",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Update:

You could also add a Mapping Char Filter to the analyzer used on the name fields (or whatever field in which the single quotation is a problem:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "' => "
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you run:

```
POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "O'Bryan is a good"
}
```

You will get:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "OBryan",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "is",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "a",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "good",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 17,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So while storing `person_name` , `name` and `office.name` i have to use   Tokenizers ?

Comment: Right, even if you didn't specify it, you are using the standard tokenizer by default, but you can use any tokenizer that suits your needs at either index or search time.

Comment: when the user passes the query field ORyan instead if O'Ryan it doesn't return anything in that way. As you have checked with analyzer, it consider o and ryan 2 differents tokens, so if you will search for ORyan it will return anything

Comment: @Lupanoide, what i have to do to get the search result for `ORyan` as `O'Ryan`

Comment: @kgangadhar Look at the update, it will convert O'Ryan to ORyan, so it doesn't matter if the user inputs any of them, they are always treated as ORyan

Comment: @FelipePlazas In this way it doesn't work anymore for searching O'Ryan with the apostrophe. Char_filter replace the term, so in that way there is no apostrophe for all the entries, you can't search for o'Ryan

Comment: @FelipePlazas You should look at the output of your analyzer, the apostrophe there is no more

Comment: @Lupanoide that's exactly the outcome I wanted. In some cases, it might be useful to just strip the apostrophe, as both O'Ryan or  ORyan would output the same token.

Comment: @FelipePlazas this is sure, but is not what kgangadhar has asked.